# How do I annotate the decorator for a methods?

Tags: python, methods, python-decorators, python-typing

For example I have a class with a bunch of similar methods:

```py
class Actions:
    def action1(self, parameter1: int) -> None:
        ...

    def action2(self, parameter2: int) -> None:
        ...
```

And I want to create a decorator for these methods, which has access to `self`:

```py
def action(method: Callable[???]) -> Callable[???]:
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
    return wrapper
```

What should the annotations for this decorator looks like?

Currently I've tried something like this:

```py
from typing_extensions import Concatenate, ParamSpec
from typing import Callable


P = ParamSpec("P")


def action(
    method: Callable[Concatenate[Actions, P], None]
) -> Callable[Concatenate[Actions, P], None]:
    def wrapper(self: Actions, *_args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> None:
        method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
```

`Actions` here is a protocol of a class with just necessary attributes.

I am unsure, if this is a good way to do it. Mypy seems to understand it, while Pycharm, for example, complains about any call like `actions.action1(parameter1=0)` with `Expected type 'Actions', got 'int' instead`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle I would say your approach is perfectly fine. The PyCharm type checker is indeed bugged with decorated methods sometimes. I am not sure, if it is the `Concatenate` or something else that trips it up. But I would rely more on Mypy anyway.

If it were up to me, I would make the decorator as generic as possible. Even assuming that the internal wrapper it produces *relies* on the instance implementing a specific protocol, you could still make it generic in terms of the *specific* type that matches the protocol, the parameter specification (as you already did), *and* the return type. The latter would make it not restricted to methods that return some specific type (like `None` in your example).

A type variable can actually have a (non-generic) protocol as its upper bound, so we could annotate this quite nicely. If we assume that the protocol simply requires an instance method called `some_required_method` without additional parameters and a `None` return to be implemented, the code might look like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import Concatenate, ParamSpec


P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")
A = TypeVar("A", bound="ActionsProtocol")


class ActionsProtocol(Protocol):
    def some_required_method(self) -> None:
        ...


def action(
    method: Callable[Concatenate[A, P], R]
) -> Callable[Concatenate[A, P], R]:
    def wrapper(self: A, /, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        output = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
        self.some_required_method()  # <-- why we need the upper bound for `A`
        return output
    return wrapper
```

(Note that we need to mark the `self` parameter of the `wrapper` as **positional-only**.)

Usage:

```py
class Actions:
    def some_required_method(self) -> None:
        print("whatever")

    @action
    def action1(self, parameter1: int) -> int:
        return parameter1 ** 2

    @action
    def action2(self, parameter2: str) -> None:
        print(parameter2)


a = Actions()
result = a.action1(2)  # false positive by PyCharm
print(result)
a.action2("foo")       # false positive by PyCharm
```

Output:

```
whatever
4
foo
whatever
```

If we now add the following lines:

```py
reveal_type(Actions.action1)
reveal_type(Actions.action2)
reveal_type(result)
```

And run that entire code through `mypy --strict`, we get no errors and the following output:

```
note: Revealed type is "def (Actions, parameter1: builtins.int) -> builtins.int"
note: Revealed type is "def (Actions, parameter2: builtins.str)"
note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
```

Notice that the versions of the methods that are *not bound* to an instance yet (e.g. `Actions.action1`) show the first parameter to be of type `Actions` now. With your initial approach the type of that first parameter would be that of the `ActionsProtocol`, so arguably too permissive.

Here is a [Mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=898460b5b9734d527d15e2dbcbbcf3d0) for you to check the entire code.

---

**PS**: I searched through the JetBrains issue tracker and did not find one corresponding to this *exactly*, so I opened a [new one here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-60954). We'll see how this goes.